# install Salome-Meca - Code_Aster in Linux Mint 20.2 requires a successful "sudo apt install build-essential"

Tags: linux-mint

I need to install Salome-Meca - Code_Aster on a Linux Mint 20.2 machine. This software requires a series of extra modules (see https://www.code-aster.org/V2/spip.php?article303).

When typing on the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install build-essential
```

I always get the following message after the third command line instruction:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:9.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I overcome this? I have read elsewhere that the solution is to "downgrade". Downgrade what? And how?

Comment: Duplicate of [Windows 11, WSL with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS: cannot perform "sudo apt install build-essential" because of missing dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545032/windows-11-wsl-with-ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-cannot-perform-sudo-apt-install-build)

Comment: I opted to place two different questions in order not to pollute one with the other. I gather that the answer might be the same, but the underlying question, and OS, is different. Anyway, thanks for establishing the connection between both questions, I hope that will help getting a solution faster.